# Lift a key’s values to top level whilst preserving rest of object using Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I would like to build it into my `compose` function so that `record`’s values go to the top level of the object, whilst the rest of the keys stay in tact:

```
{
  record: {
    seasons: [
      1
    ],
    colors: [
      2
    ]
  },
  tag_ids: [
    2091
  ]
}
```

The result I am after:

```
{
  seasons: [
    1
  ],
  colors: [
    2
  ],
  tag_ids: [
    2091
  ]
}
```

Any of the keys *may* or *may not* exist.

I have always scratched my head with the ramda way to do it in a `compose` function. Currently I am looking at `toPairs` and doing some pretty long winded transforms with no luck.

Comment: So are you just looking to pull record up 1 level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use R.chain with R.merge and R.prop to flatten a key's content by merging it with the original object, and then you can omit the original key.

```js
const { pipe, chain, merge, prop, omit } = R

const fn = key => pipe(
  chain(merge, prop(key)), // flatten the key's content
  omit([key]) // remove the key
)

const data = { record: { seasons: [1], colors: [2] }, tag_ids: [2091] }

const result = fn('record')(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is a bit verbose, `chain . merge` is not necessary imo.

Comment: Perhaps slightly simpler is `key => lift (mergeLeft) (prop (key), omit ([key]))`.

Answer (score 3):

This may be simpler in plain JS rather than Ramda:

```
const data = { record: { seasons: [1], colors: [2] }, tag_ids: [2091] }

const flattenRecord = ({record = {}, ...rest}) => ({...record, ...rest})

flattenRecord(data) //=> {"colors": [2], "seasons": [1], "tag_ids": [2091]}
```

If you would still like to utilise Ramda for the solution, consider looking into [`R.mergeLeft`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mergeLeft) (or `R.mergeRight`) and [`R.omit`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#omit).

Comment: Nice one. You don't need the record default value since object spread ignores `undefined` values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spread operator.

```js
const startingWithAllProps = {
  record: {
    seasons: [
      1
    ],
    colors: [
      2
    ]
  },
  tag_ids: [
    2091
  ]
}

const startingWithoutRecord = {
  tag_ids: [
    2091
  ]
}

const startingWithoutTagIds = {
  record: {
    seasons: [
      1
    ],
    colors: [
      2
    ]
  }
}

const moveRecordUpOneLevel = (startingObject) => {
  const temp = {
    ...startingObject.record,
    tag_ids: startingObject.tag_ids
  }
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp)) // To remove any undefined props
}

const afterTransformWithAllProps = moveRecordUpOneLevel(startingWithAllProps)
const afterTransformWithoutRecord = moveRecordUpOneLevel(startingWithoutRecord)
const afterTransformWithoutTagIds = moveRecordUpOneLevel(startingWithoutTagIds)

console.log('afterTransformWithAllProps', afterTransformWithAllProps)
console.log('afterTransformWithoutRecord', afterTransformWithoutRecord)
console.log('afterTransformWithoutTagIds', afterTransformWithoutTagIds)
```

Comment: The `record` field may not exist.

Comment: What would your desired output be if `record` does not exist? Because if you want to just leave the rest of the object how it is, the above method will still work.

Answer (score 1):

This might help too!

```js
const lift = key => R.converge(R.mergeRight, [
  R.dissoc(key),
  R.prop(key),
]);

const liftRecord = lift('record');

// ====
const data = {
  record: {
    seasons: [
      1
    ],
    colors: [
      2
    ]
  },
  tag_ids: [
    2091
  ]
};

console.log(
  liftRecord(data),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-buL0byPvI/XRDFscnSc/e0q+sLA65O9y+rbF+0O/4FE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Oh yes, nice solution too. Thank you!